# Merge Docx with PHP with different formatting

Tags: php, xml, merge, ms-word, docx

Using DocxMerge I can merge several Docx documents into one Word document. I've modified this to add page breaks between the documents by replacing the end w:body tag with this code:

```
<w:p><w:r><w:br w:type="page" /></w:r></w:p>
```

However, the document formatting is not right. For example, one document is centre aligned, and the other is left - they continue with the alignment of whichever document is placed first.

There is also an issue with different margins..

The issue seems to lie with styles.xml however I lack the knowledge of Word XML to merge the two styles.xml. There could be a possibility of saving the word document with styles.xml 'hardcoded' within the main document which would solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Less ideal

To answer your question: Yes it is possible to 'hardcode' formatting styles, but that's a lot of work and prone to failure.

If a Word template was used, you have the (character) style inside the `document.xml` like this:

```
<w:r>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rStyle w:val="myStyle"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>My content</w:t>
</w:r>
```

And the formatting inside the `styles.xml` like this:

```
<w:style w:type="character" w:styleId="myStyle">
    <w:name w:val="myStyle"/>
    <w:rsid w:val="003504C8"/>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:color w:val="0000FF"/>
        <w:u w:val="single"/>
    </w:rPr>
</w:style>
```

To add it as a manual formatting remove the `w:rStyle` element and replace it with the `w:rPr` element content:

```
<w:r>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:color w:val="0000FF"/>
        <w:u w:val="single"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>My content</w:t>
</w:r>
```

That works only on simple styles. Styles with numbering for example are more complicated.

**Page margin**: The page margins are set in the `document.xml` file (not `styles.xml`) inside the `w:sectPr` -> `w:pgMar` element. The unit used is [twips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twip).

#### Better

It would be better, if your source document were written using the same Word template, so there would (or should) be no conflict in styles or page margin.

Comment: Thank you for your insight Martin. Yes my main issue is merging two documents that use different word templates. I need a way to merge the different template styles with each new document.

Comment: My best work around has been to "trick" word into modifying the document rather than the template it sits in, if this makes any sense. But I could really do with a way to automate this.